# how to connect with a live database in tableau using ssh tunneling?

Tags: postgresql, tableau-desktop

I have a PostgreSQL database hosted in private network. i have bastion id, username ,database credentials. how can I connect the database with tableau using ssh key?  so far  i did not find any viable solution for this problem. I need a solution where tableau with get connected with the database and get live data.

Answer (score 0):

If Tableau doesn't have integrated tools to create the tunnel (and as far as I know it doesn't) then you can create a tunnel yourself using `ssh` or `putty` or some python module, for example.  Then tell Tableau Desktop to connect to the database at the address of the local end of the tunnel, likely 127.0.0.1:5432.

Comment: if I do then then what will happen if my local machine is off and someone want ot acces a report in tableau?

Comment: If you are using the desktop product, how are they going to access it when the desktop is off, anyway?

Comment: but my database is a live database hosted in amazon aurora. my client will download the reports whenever they need it.so only able to connect the database when local machine is on is not a solution for me